# range is not a function in lodash?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have lodash cdn included in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/byhh6Lyo/

```
console.log(_)
console.log(_.range(1, 10))
_.map([1,2,3], (o) => console.log(o)) //worked
```

The second line has an error, saying `range is not a function`, what's wrong?

Comment: You're loading `lodash.core.min.js`, which is a subset of the full suite of lodash functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cdn you are using is not correct. You were using `core` version which does not contain `_.range`. `core` build has very limited features available. Check here for more information : https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Build-Differences

**Solution**: Use the full version => https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js

Below is working fine:

```js
console.log(_)
console.log(_.range(1, 10))
_.map([1, 2, 3], (o) => console.log(o)) //worked
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```